# register allocation for x86

Tags: compiler-construction, x86, code-generation, register-allocation

I am attempting a simple register allocation with x86. Am using the linear register allocator but I have a few questions on some simple things which I am not finding the information about.

```
int main()
{
    int a, b, c;
    a = 10;
    b = 20;
    c = 2;
    a = a + b;
    b = b * 5;
    c = c * b + a;
    return c;
}
```

For this simple code, ignoring constant propagation, g++ & msvc generate similar code which pushes all temporaries on the stack and then uses eax, ebx etc only for ALU ops. Clang generates the following code with O0.

```
main:                                   # @main
    movl    $0, -4(%rsp)
    movl    $10, -8(%rsp)
    movl    $20, -12(%rsp)
    movl    $2, -16(%rsp)
    movl    -8(%rsp), %eax
    addl    -12(%rsp), %eax
    movl    %eax, -8(%rsp)
    imull   $5, -12(%rsp), %eax
    movl    %eax, -12(%rsp)
    movl    -16(%rsp), %eax
    imull   -12(%rsp), %eax
    addl    -8(%rsp), %eax
    movl    %eax, -16(%rsp)
    movl    -16(%rsp), %eax
    ret
```

As is evident, that all temporaries are on the stack. So my question is based on this same thing. **At any point, should anything in eax/ebx etc which are used in add/mul/div operations etc have a lifetime more than 1 instruction. That is, should any live range interval have its value stored in these registers or should they be evicted as soon as the register allocation is done and their values pushed to temporaries ?**

Or can we use some of these registers till the next ALU instruction is encountered and do a lazy push to stack when necessary?

Comment: You can pretty much do whatever you want as long as you preserve `esp` and the callee save registers. The reason why compilers shove everything on the stack without optimization is because it's easier that way. (no register allocation at all)

Comment: Thanks Mystical. I understand that. My question was more geared towards when this can't be optimized. For example, the values of a,b,c are not constants but rather from arguments. In that case, for a register allocator to kick in, would it ever store anything in registers or will it still be on the stack. For example, even on MSVC I see that when it can't optimize, it uses eax etc only for alu. Not for storing any intermediate values.

Comment: It's a much more complicated than that. MSVC likes use `eax` because it's the "1st" register. What's really happening in the compiler (with optimizations) is that it makes a graph where nodes are values and then solves a graph coloring problem. Each color is a different register. In simple functions, the graph is simple and only 1 or 2 colors are needed. MSVC apparently likes to use `eax` as the first color.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. I understand what graph coloring is doing in this case. What I am rather asking is that since eax is used in say mul/div instructions, is that why they are not being used for any live ranges? Only alu operations seem to use the general purpose registers and all temporaries are living on stack. So can this be optimized more where instead of storing temporaries on stack, if they can be stored in the GPR's or since they have to be spilled, whenever an ALU happens, the compiler prefers to precolor these and put them on stack?

Comment: Are you asking about optimized or not optimized code? The answer is very different. The example you have shown above is not optimized. The compiler does not do register allocation and simply assigns a stack location to all variables and temporaries. The only reason it uses registers at all is because the instructions themselves operate on registers. In this case, it only uses `eax` because it only needs to use one register.

Comment: Actually I was asking about the optimized code. The above example is probably not the right one. With constant propagation, it reduces to 1 statement. However, the case when a,b,c are not constants, I still see MSVC generating code storing these temporaries onto the stack with O3. So that's why I was wondering, how it was precoloring these to not use the GPR's. I will edit the question to include the optimized version of the code.

Comment: eax is (or was) special http://www.swansontec.com/sregisters.html